# calling a method in js file which is defined in other js files jquery

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a implemented a method in file1.js file as

```
function setlist(){
 db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}
```

and I am trying to call this method in my file2.js as

```
$(function() {
    setlist();
    });
```

But the method is not getting called and i am getting the error as `05-19 14:05:37.545: E/Web Console(9341): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setlist at file`

What is the mistake i am doing?

Thanks:)

Comment: What is the order of loading? Mainly is all of your javascript initialized in a HEAD content?

Answer (score 0):

Seems nothing wrong.

Make sure file1.js get imported before file2.js

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
The order of scripts are ok and changing it gived me no result.

So, I put my function out of the file1.js (function(){})(); scope and it works!

from:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        //do my things
    };

  function myFunction(){
    //do the things your fucntion do
  };

})();
```

to:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        //do my things
    };
})();

function myFunction(){
  //do the things your fucntion do
};
```

Please, let me know if it helps you.